# Magento-2 How to convert price from current currency to base currency

Tags: magento2, multicurrency, convert

I want to convert product price from the current currency to base currency.

For Example, if the product price is 5000 INR. I want to convert 5000 **INR** to **USD**.

I don't know which core function will be best used for. Can anyone give me examples? Any function which is used for convert price to **current to base** and **base to current**?

**Purpose**: I am adding a product to cart programmatically, if a current currency is USD then it's working properly but if I switch currency as **INR**, added product price convert **INR** amount to **USD**. So I want to convert INR amount to USD.

Comment: could you please help me . I have posted a new question (compare store currency & getCurrentCurrency) please check it on my profile .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
public function convertPrice($amount = 0, $store = null, $currency = null)
{
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $priceCurrencyObject = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface'); 
    //instance of PriceCurrencyInterface
    $storeManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface'); 
    //instance of StoreManagerInterface
    if ($store == null) {
        $store = $storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId(); 
        //get current store id if store id not get passed
    }
    $rate = $priceCurrencyObject->convert($amount, $store, $currency); 
    //it return price according to current store from base currency
 
    //If you want it in base currency then use:
    $rate = $this->_priceCurrency->convert($amount, $store) / $amount;
    $amount = $amount / $rate;
     
    return $amount;

}
```

Here, `$amount` is the amount to which you want to convert.

`$store` is the store id, from which store’s base currency you want to convert.

`$currency` is the currency whom you want to convert, if you passed null then it takes current currency.

Comment: @SureshChikani, I have added another solution, I hope it will work.

Comment: Also check by `return $amount` insted of `return $priceCurrencyObject->round($amount);` @SureshChikani

Comment: Hope your issue is resolved @SureshChikani

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79263/discussion-between-nikunj-vadariya-and-suresh-chikani).

Comment: You should never use `ObjectManager`

Comment: could you please help me . I have posted a new question (compare store currency & getCurrentCurrency) please check it on my profile .

Comment: I don't know why this answer is accepted while there is a bug in the answer "$this->_priceCurrency" variable is not defined anywhere in the code

Answer (score 5):

You can use below code in your helper or in a function

```
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory
     */
    protected $currencyFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory $currencyFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory $currencyFactory
    ){
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->currencyFactory = $currencyFactory;
    }


    public function convertToBaseCurrency($price)
    {
        //you can also pass INR code here insted of below current store currency
        $currentCurrency = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentCurrency()->getCode();

        $baseCurrency = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseCurrency()->getCode();

        $rate = $this->currencyFactory->create()->load($currentCurrency)->getAnyRate($baseCurrency);
        $returnValue = $price * $rate;

        return $returnValue;
    }
```

Comment: I have used same code but facing the issue, it will not return proper value.

Comment: could you please help me . I have posted a new question (compare store currency & getCurrentCurrency) please check it on my profile .

Answer (score 2):

Magento itself provides all the convert configuration we only need to use it.

The simplest way to archive this!

```
class Price 
{

    protected $_priceHelper;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data $priceHelper,

    ) {
        $this->_priceHelper = $priceHelper;
    }

    public function yourFunction(){
        /* Your code  */
        $this->convertToBaseCurrency(100);
    }

    /**
     * @param $price
     * @return int|float
     */
    public function convertToBaseCurrency($price)
    {
        $formattedCurrencyValue = $this->_priceHelper->currency($price, false, false);
        return $formattedCurrencyValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: You also get the price with currency code or without just going to currency function in priceHelper.

Answer (score 0):

**Try not to use Objectmanager. It is just for fast implementation**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
// if 1 USD = 2 INR 
// and current store currency is USD
$amount = 45;
$priceCurr = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface');
echo $priceCurr->convertAndFormat($amount, false, 3, null, "INR"); 
// output $90
```

1. amount
2. include container set false or true ( < span >$90 < /span>).
3. set precision (3).
4. Specify scope.
5. Convert currency to (INR), By default this will convert to current store currency from base currency.